# Should I delete the branch after CLOSING the pull request?

Tags: git, github

In our project, we were working on a feature. We finished the development, created a pull request and after some comments closed it (Not merged). But the management decided not to go ahead with the feature releasing/publishing. Now I am not sure whether or not we should delete the branch! Can any one guide me what to do with the branch? So that it should not appear in the branch list, but the code should be preserved for future references!

Comment: You can create another git repo on the side with some features that as not been published? Like a fork or something like that?

Comment: A good trick though! But perhaps organizational policy may not allow us to do so!

Comment: would creating a tag be an option?

Comment: Let's suppose that I create a tag, then where the code would reside? In the master branch or somewhere else?

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you checkout master, the code won't be there, if this is what you are asking

Comment: @Francesco right..!!! Would we lose the code that way?

Comment: of course not.. I will ad an answer to explain it better

Comment: Similiar question on softwareengineering.SE: [What do you do with branches you've abandoned?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450379/what-do-you-do-with-branches-youve-abandoned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in a situation as the graph below

```
* 9ee0852 (HEAD -> master) some work
| * b7bfb4f (feature) some work on branch
| * 6c3e2f3 some work on branch
|/
* cf51f19 some work
* f850633 some work
```

and you want to:

- remove the feature branch so that the list of branches is clean
- keep the feature work in the repository for future reference
- have the master branch clean, i.e. without the changes introduced by the new feature

I suggest you to create a tag where the feature branch is and delete the branch, so that you end up with a structure like this (mostly the same)

```
* 9ee0852 (HEAD -> master) some work
| * b7bfb4f (tag: feature) some work on branch
| * 6c3e2f3 some work on branch
|/
* cf51f19 some work
* f850633 some work
```

**Explanation in few points**

- *Which code is lost and which is kept?*: git eventually deletes commits
  not referenced by other commits, branches or tags. So the commits of
  the new feature are not deleted since you have the tag
- Note: in git branches and tags are just pointers to commits, so there's nothing like *code that resides in a branch*
- *What code is shown when you checkout a branch (master is also a branch)?*: the code contained in the commit referenced by the branch label. Git uses a snapshot model for commits, i.e. every commit contains a full snapshot of the repository at the moment the commit was made.
- *I do not understand the point above*: In your case having a branch or a tag is the same. Did you have the changes of the feature branch when you checked out master? No. So you will not have them in master also with the tag.
- *But I want to understand!*: good! It is not so easy to explain all this stuff in a simple post. Go on searching and studying git, maybe starting with git book